# Navbar using js. Link not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have download a navigation bar template and struggling to make it work as I want it to. When a heading is clicked it opens a sub menu to have further links. I do not want all headings to open the sub menu, I want some to just be a link I.E home.

When home is clicked it just highlights home as if opening the submenu and doesnt go to the link. I think this is a js issue.

Below is the html:

```
<nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">

                    <ul>
                                <li>
                            <a href="home.php">Home</a>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Club Information</a>
                            <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>About the Club</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="about.php">About IDMC</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="location.php">Where to Find Us</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="whatwedo.php">What We Do</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <h4>Contacting Us</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="contactus.php">General Information</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div></div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
                            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

I believe this is the js causing the issue but not sure what to change:

```
var cbpHorizontalMenu=(function(){var b=$("#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li"),g=b.children("a"),c=$("body"),d=-1;function f(){g.on("click",a);b.on("click",function(h){h.stopPropagation()})}function a(j){if(d!==-1){b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen")}var i=$(j.currentTarget).parent("li"),h=i.index();if(d===h){i.removeClass("cbp-hropen");d=-1}else{i.addClass("cbp-hropen");d=h;c.off("click").on("click",e)}return false}function e(h){b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen");d=-1}return{init:f}})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to exclude the items that are just links, not dropdowns. So, add a class of `link` to the links that have no sub-items. `<a href="home.php" class="link">Home</a>`

Then change the Javascript to look like this: The code should then not run on the links with a class of link.

```
var cbpHorizontalMenu=(function(){
  var b=$("#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li"), g=b.children("a").not($('.link')), c=$("body"), d=-1;
  function f(){
    g.on("click",a);
    b.on("click", function(h){
      h.stopPropagation();
    })
  }
  function a(j){
    if(d!==-1){
      b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen");
    }
    var i=$(j.currentTarget).parent("li"), h=i.index();
    if(d===h){
      i.removeClass("cbp-hropen");
      d=-1
    }else{
      i.addClass("cbp-hropen");
      d=h;
      c.off("click").on("click",e);
    }
    return false
  }
  function e(h){
    b.eq(d).removeClass("cbp-hropen");
    d=-1
  }
  return {init:f}
 })();
```